# Javascript: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript

My Code was running properly.
But suddenly it stopped working and giving this error-

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

How to debug this error ?
I didn't change anything but still it's giving this error.

The code is mentioned below-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js">
</script>

<script>


var marker;

<!--Intializing the script for displaying map-->

function initialize()
{
<!--url_arrays will store the arrays passed as url parameter,url is the encoded url with parameter passed to the iframe without '?' and '&' character which is used to separate the parameters from the url-->
var url_arrays = [],url_param;
    var url = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
<!--if the subtring contains any '=' character it will remove them & will store them in url_arrays array-->
    for (var i = 0; i < url.length; i++)
    {
        url_param = url[i].split('=');
        url_arrays.push(url_param[0]);
        url_arrays[url_param[0]] = url_param[1];
    }

<!--As the url is in encoded format, it has to be decoded-->
var lat_tmp = decodeURIComponent(url_arrays[0]).split(','||' ');
var long_tmp = decodeURIComponent(url_arrays[1]).split(','||' ');

<!-- these arrays will contain the lattitude & longitude values-->
var lattitude=[];
var longitude=[];

<!--The negetive or posive value has to be extracted from the string-->
    for (var i = 0; i < lat_tmp.length; i++) 
    {
       lattitude.push(parseFloat(lat_tmp[i].match(/-?\d*\.{0,1}\d+/), 10));
       longitude.push(parseFloat(long_tmp[i].match(/-?\d*\.{0,1}\d+/), 10));
    }


<!--Finding the maximum, minimum value of lattitude & longitude array. It will be useful to set auto zoom of the map -->
var max_lattitude=lattitude[0],min_lattitude=lattitude[0];
var max_longitude=longitude[0],min_longitude=longitude[0];

    for(var i=0;i<lattitude.length;i++)
    {
       if(max_lattitude<lattitude[i])
     max_lattitude=lattitude[i];
       if(min_lattitude>lattitude[i])
     min_lattitude=lattitude[i];

       if(max_longitude<longitude[i])
     max_longitude=longitude[i];
       if(min_longitude>longitude[i])
     min_longitude=longitude[i];
    }

<!--Finding the center of the co-ordinates-->
var lattitude_center=(max_lattitude+min_lattitude)/2;
var longitude_center=(max_longitude+min_longitude)/2;

document.getElementById("lattitude").innerHTML = max_lattitude+" : "+min_lattitude;
document.getElementById("longitude").innerHTML = max_longitude+" : "+min_longitude;

var mapObject = {
  center:new google.maps.LatLng(lattitude_center,longitude_center),
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapObject);

for(var i=0;i<lattitude.length;i++)
{

var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(lattitude[i],longitude[i]);
var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
  position:myCenter,
  animation:google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
  });

<!--Auto zooming the map based on the minimum & maximun lattitude, longitude-->
map.fitBounds(new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
//bottom left
new google.maps.LatLng(min_lattitude, min_longitude),
//top right
new google.maps.LatLng(max_lattitude, max_longitude)
));
marker.setMap(map);
}
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>
Lattitude: <div id="lattitude"/></div>
Longitude: <div id="longitude"/></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried different web browser. But the problem remains same.

Comment: Give use the code please. It's a Bufferoverflow

Comment: @schnawel007: It’s a stack overflow, not a buffer overflow.

Comment: Show us the code. This errors almost occur while encoding/decoding complete model instead of item.

Comment: I have updated my answer with the code.
This code was working perfectly earlier.

Comment: What’s the stack trace for the error? On what line does it occur?

Comment: `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`  `main.js:26` `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`  `main.js:17`
this is all I'm getting in console

Comment: I don't know. Try to run this code in Chrome. press F12. There in console you can see the stack trace

Comment: What parameters are you adding to the querystring?

Comment: The problem is solved. Actually the query string I'm passing is dynamic. This time one of the value was null. That's why it was giving that error.
Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

`map.fitBounds()` function is throwing this error.

### Reasons

- Either it's not receiving latitude/longitude or both.
- The received values of latitude/longitude are not in correct format(NaN).